# How to join two tables and make group by in Linq

Tags: linq

I have a question about Linq select statement. I am new to Linq so any help will be very helpful. I did a lot of research but I still didn't manage to write down correct Linq statement.

I have this two tables and attributes:

```
Table Titles(title_id(PK), title) and
Table Sales(title_id(PK), qty)
```

where are `title_id` and title string values and qty is a number which represents some quantity.

I need to write a select which will take five most selling titles from this two tables.
So, I need to make sum from qty (we can have more records with the same `Sales.title_id` attribute) and make group by `title_id` and order by `sum(qty)` descending and then return attributes title and `title_id`.

How can I make suitable solution for my question?

Regards,
Dahakka

Comment: Are you using something like the Entity Framework? Or Linq to Sql?

Comment: Yes, I code ASP .Net service and application and I use Linq to searching for data in tables. That's why I needed to get this querry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do group join of tables by `title_id` (each group `g` will represent all sales of joined title). Then select title description and total of sales for that title. Order result by totals, select title and take required number of top sales titles:

```
var query = (from t in db.Titles
             join s in db.Sales on t.title_id equals s.title_id into g
             select new { Title = t.title, Total = g.Sum(x => x.qty) } into ts
             orderby ts.Total descending
             select ts.Title).Take(5);
```

Resulting SQL will look like:

```
SELECT TOP (5) [t2].[title] AS [Title], [t2].[value] AS [Total]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[title_id], (
        SELECT SUM([t1].[qty])
        FROM [Sales] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t0].[title_id] = [t1].[title_id]
        ) AS [value]
    FROM [Titles] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[value] DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This was almost what I needed, thanks! You saved me a lot of time. I really apreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Following is the linq query in method syntax

```
    sales.GroupBy(s=>s.title_id)
    .Select ( x =>  
       new {
           Title_id = x.Key, 
            Sales= x.Sum (x=> x.qty)
        })
    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Sales).Take(5)
        .Join( titles, 
            sale=>sale.Title_id,
            title=> title.title_id, 
            (sale, title)=> new 
                {
                  Title = title.Title, 
                  TotalSales=sale.Sales
                }
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to. With both examples I did make a further step of understanding Linq. Thanks again!